# Prolog return value comparation

Tags: list, prolog, return

I'm traying to learn the basics of logic programming.
I solved some exercises, and now I'm having trouble on creating a function that take two arguments, a list of non empty lists whose elements concatenated together form the second argument.

By the time I created a function that concat the elements of a list of lists:

```
concat([[]|L],L3):- concat(L,L3).
concat([[Head|L1]|L2],[Head|L3]):- concat([L1|L2],L3),!.
```

Now, what I need to know is how to take the return value of that function and compare it with a list (the second argument of the function).

Comment: Prolog doesn't have *functions* with *return values*. Prolog has *predicates* that define *relations* between its arguments. It's a little unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: What happens if `L` is `[]`?

Comment: concat([],[]). But I think it is not necessary because I break the recursion with the !.

Comment: Recursion eliminates solutions. It doesn't add them. And it's not a substitute for a proper terminal case, since that case must succeed on its own. What should the result of `concat([[]], L)` be? And what is it when you try it in your program?

Comment: In my programa that should be false, because the first argument can't be a list of empty lists. If I try it in my program it is L=[ ]

Comment: `concat([[1]], L)` will fail as well with your code because you need a proper base case. I assume it should yield, `L = [1]`. A cut does not substitute for a proper base case. And if you have a proper base case, you probably don't need the cut.

Comment: Yes, I need to change the base case, but what i really don't know how to do, is compare the two lists. For example:

Comment: compare([[1]],[1]). should be true, because concat([[1]],L)==[1]    other example:  compare([[1,2],[3,4],[5,[6,7],8]], [1,2,3,4,5,[6,7],8]). should be true

Comment: You don't need to change the base case. Your fundamental base case is missing. You need to *add* the base case, which is `concat([[L]], [L]).`.

Comment: Oh my god... thats it. Thank you so much for investing your time helping me. Can you make me a short explanation of how is that base case working in the "function"?

Comment: `concat([[L]], ...)` is what your recursion reduces down to when you've exhausted all but the last list element inside the first argument. Your `concat([[]|L], ...)` clause handles the case where the current element reduces to empty, and then moves to the next list element in the first argument. For your compare, `compare(X, Y) :- concat(X, C), C = Y.` assuming order of elements matters.

Comment: Huum, I see it now. I only see a problema, if you compare for exaple, compare([[1,2],[ ],[3]],[1,2,3]). , it should be true and I think it shouldn't, because the empty list in the first argument.

Comment: `compare([[1,2],[],[3]], [1,2,3])` is true because `concat('[[1,2],[],[3]], [1,2,3])` is true. Why should the former be false if the latter is true? Or did you really want `concat('[[1,2],[],[3]], [1,2,3])` to be false, which means your `concat` predicate needs more work? You need to state your requirements clearly regarding the handling of `[]`.

Comment: I think that the concat predicate have to be modified, because [[1,2],[ ],[3]] is not a list of non-empty lists.

Comment: That means your `concat([[]|L], L3)...` case is incorrect because it is a rule that allows an empty sublist.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm traying to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach that will allow down to single elements in a sublist, but not an empty sublist:

```
concat([[L]], [L]).
concat([[H],L|T], [H|R]) :- concat([L|T], R).
concat([[H1,H2|T]|LT], [H1|RT]) :- concat([[H2|T]|LT], RT).
```

The method here to avoid an empty list is to call out two head elements in the recursive clause, and a solitary element list in the base case. This prevents empty sublists from succeeding, as requested in the comments of the original post.

If you have a variable, `Y` that is already instantiated, and you want to know if it is the result of concatenating the list of lists, `LL`, you simply query:

```
concat(LL, Y).
```

This will be `true` if `Y` is the concatenation of list `LL` and `false` if it is not. You don't have to "return and compare" (as, for example, in C, you might say, `concat(LL) == Y`, or `concat(LL, X); if (X == Y)...`). This is because `concat` is a *relation* defined between the two arguments and it determine if the query can be made `true` by following the stated rules (clauses of the predicate).

If you already obtained a result and want to determine if it's unifiable to another variable, `Z`, then you can say:

```
concat(X, Y), Y = Z.
```

Note that, in Prolog, `concat(X, Y) == Z` is not correct to determine if the result of the predicate is equal to `Z` because it is not a function that returns a value.

Comment: That's perfect, just a point. I was thinking yesterday about that and I come more or less to the same conclusión that you. But i have added a break "!" after concat([[H],L|T], [H|R]) :- concat([L|T], R). to force the predicate to return only one true or false. And I created a: compare(X, Y) :- concat(X, C), C = Y. , just to know what second argument will fit with the first one. For example: compare([[1,2],[3,4]],L). should be L=[1,2,3,4].

Comment: @Saturnino, I tend to leave the cut out unless it's absolutely necessary. If you include the break in this case, it's because you're trying to make the predicate behave in a more imperative way (give it an input and get one output). But, without the break, queries such as `concat(L, [1,2,3]).` will show you all the possible values of `L` which concatenate to `[1,2,3]`. With the cut in place, this query will not yield all of the correct answers since they've been pruned by the cut. That's the issue with using cuts: they can eliminate possible alternative solutions. Use with caution.

Comment: You're right, in this case the cut Works for me because I try to know the value of the second argument of compare, and its only one possible solution. But in the case I want to know the value of the first argument, as you have exposed above, the cut would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Prolog doesn't have functions or return values in the sense of a procedural programming language. It has *predicates*, which assert a relationship. It has terms, which include *variables* which comes with some strictures:

- All variables are local, and
- A variable, once assigned a value, **ceases to be variable**. That's why it's called *unification*.

So....

If you want a predicate that will take two lists and produce their concatenation, you'll need to pass it a 3rd variable. You might invoke it like this:

```
concat([a,b],[c,d],X).
```

which asserts that `X` is the concatenation of `[a,b]` and `[c,d]`. Prolog's inference engine will then evaluate the truth or falseness of the assertion.

Most recursive problems has a few special cases and a more general case. The implementation of such a `concat/3` predicate might look something like this (annotated to explain what it's doing).

- First, we have one special (and terminating) case: If the left-hand list is empty, the concatenation is simply the right-hand list.

  concat( [] , Bs , Bs ).
- Next, we have the one general case: if the left-hand list is non-empty, we need to prepend it to the concatentation that we're building (and then recurse down.)

  concat( [A|As] , Bs , [A|Cs] ) :-
    concat(As,Bs,Cs).

That's all there is two it. You'll also notice that it's bi-directional: it's perfectly happy to split lists apart as well. Invoking it like this:

```
concat( Prefix , Suffix,  [a,b,c,d] ).
```

will, on backtracking, produce all the possible ways that `[a,b,c,d]` could be split into a prefix and suffix:

```
Prefix    Suffix
--------- ---------
[]        [a,b,c,d]
[a]       [b,c,d]
[a,b]     [c,d]
[a,b,c]   [d]
[a,b,c,d] []
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the base case

```
concat([],[]).
concat([[]|L],L3):- concat(L,L3).
concat([[Head|L1]|L2],[Head|L3]):- concat([L1|L2],L3).
```

It also works for empty (sub)lists.
I've removed the useless cut.

Comment: The OP indicated, buried deep in one of his comments to his post, that he doesn't want empty sublists to succeed.